# Sending output to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am very new to the ELK stack and I am having some difficulty wrapping my head around it.

I have a test configuration under `/etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf` that looks like this:

```
input {
    stdin { }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "test"
}
    stdout{ }
}
```

When I run `sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf` I see the output in stdout in the following form:
`2016-08-04T10:09:46.406Z myserver.local hello world`, but I don't see it apper in Kibana.

I think I might have created the index wrong, as I am not 100% sure how to do it.
[image: Kibana]

Comment: Tried your config. It created test index for me. Couldn't find anything wrong with your config.

Comment: @MrunalPagnis So was I right in presuming the `index => "name_of_index"` is the index name required by Kibana?

Comment: yes. That is right. Also you can check if index was created in elastic search by using this link in your browser `localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?v`. It will list all the indices and details.

Comment: @MrunalPagnis Thank you for your help. Just one more question: I have created another conf file (a duplicate of the other), but with a different port and index name. Even after restarting both ES and LS and running `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?v'` I am not seeing the newly created index. How can I refresh the indices?

Comment: Your port number should match. It should be the standard `9200` port number for elasticsearch. Else make sure you add other port number to elastic search config. Because elasticsearch is only configured for `9200`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments with some pointers into an answer as it solved your problem.

Using `index => "test"` is the correct way. You can also give a field value as index name using `index => "%{fieldname}"`.

1. Your config is correct. I have tested it and your config is correct. It is creating an index `test` in `elasticsearch`.
2. You can check your index is created or not by listing all the indices present in `elasticsearch` by using `localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?v` in your browser.
3. The port number which you give in your config should match the port number for which `elasticsearch` is configured. Giving a different port number without configuring in `elasticsearch` will not work. The default port number is `9200`.
4. You might also want to check if the port number you are using is already in use.
5. If all of the above is verified and index is created in `elasticsearch` then you should be able to see it in `kibana` as well. Now you can go ahead and create the `pattern` in `kibana` with the index name `test`.
6. As mentioned in @alpert's answer you should play around with the `timepicker` and adjust it to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you dont see anything because of your time interval that is at the top right of your browser. May be your document is older than that interval - it is usually `Last 15 minutes`. Change it to a bigger intevar like `Today` etc